# How to split a String based on conditions

Tags: java

Hi I need to split a String in java based on conditions 
the String might be in two formats 
1. IF the format is like this  WG/A/0-5  then I need to check if the last part starts with "0-" then I need the middle part to be extracted (ie:"A")
2.The Second format is WG/A/3-3 here it is 3-3 ie:other than 0) here I need to extract (A/3) .

I have tried like this

```
String parent = StringPool.BLANK;
if(wgCode.split(StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH)[2].startsWith("0-")) {
    parent = wgCode.split(StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH)[1];
} else if(!wgCode.split(StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH)[2].startsWith("0-")) {
    parent = wgCode.split(StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH)[1]+"/"+wgCode.split(StringPool.FORWARD_SLASH)[2].split("-")[0];
}
_log.info("parent parent"+parent);
```

Comment: Okay, what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Won't you have values that evaluate true for both?

Comment: If your strings are always as simple, you can just get the characters at the specific position. Then have an if statement which checks the number and do the appropriate thing after checking if it's 0 or non 0. But the best way to do it is to use regex - create a regular expression and check your input against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regular Expressions and `String.contains` to check your conditions and `String.indexOf` and `String.substring` to split your String.

The following method will work for your example:

```
public String getString(String input)
{
    if(input.matches(".*/.*/0.*"))
    {
        String yourString = input.substring(input.indexOf("/")+1);
        yourString = yourString.substring(0, yourString.indexOf("/"));
        return yourString;
    }
    else
    {
        String yourString = input.substring(input.indexOf("/")+1);
        yourString = yourString.substring(0, yourString.indexOf("/")+2);
        return yourString;
    }
}
```

With the regular expression `.*/.*/0.*` you find all Strings that start with a `0` after the second `/`.

Answer (score 0):

use `String#contains(String)` to check whether `0-` is there nor not.

```
String str="WG/A/0-5";
String str1="WG/A/3-3";
if(str.contains("0-"))
System.out.println(str.substring(str.indexOf("/")+1,str.indexOf("/",str.indexOf("/") + 1)));//A
if(!str1.contains("0-"))
System.out.println(str1.substring(str1.indexOf("/")+1,str1.indexOf("-")));//A/3
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
String input = "WG/A/0-5";
String[] parts = input.split("/");

if( parts[2].charAt(0) == '0' ){
......
```

Answer (score 0):

`String charAt, substring` should solve your problem:

```
String myValue = input.charAt(5) == '0' ? input.substring(3, 4) : input
        .substring(3, 6);
```